# Try to find the integration value.

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration

Given $f(z) = 
\begin{cases}
z^{2021}+1,  & \text{if $z\neq 0$} \\
2020, & \text{if $z=0$}
\end{cases}$

Then $\int_{|z|=1} f(z)= $

Here $|z|=1$ means as region " the closed circle around origin with radius $1$".

I have not done integration of this type of discontinuous complex function. May be this is easy? But please help me to find a way.

Comment: Why should you let the artificial discontinuity bother you? $f$ has an antiderivative holomorphic on an open set containing the integration path, so the answer is $0$.

Comment: If $|z|=1$ then $z\neq 0$ so $f(z)=z^{2021}+1$ which is analytic, so its integral on a closed path is zero.

Comment: @K.defaoite No ,,, here $|z|=1$ not only indicating the path,, it's the closed circle around origin with radius $1$. Sorry , for first time , I didn't include it.

Comment: @Parcly Taxel I didn't get you, please explain a little bit more. Thank you.

Comment: Is this true that if two complex functions disagree for a countable set then their integration on same region will be same?

Comment: @Alearner Yes,  Riemann integration ignores differences up to countable.  Lebesgue furthers that to ignore differences up to measure 0 sets

Comment: @Alearner Exactly, so *on the path of integration*, $f(z)=z^{2021}+1$.

Comment: You could even calculate the integral directly, by substituting $z= e^{i \phi}$, $0 \le \phi \le 2 \pi$.